# A query about adding borders using Python docx Package to a word document

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx

I am trying to write a program in Python that takes data from an Excel File and uses it to create Word Files. 
For instance, consider the following Excel File named Problems.xlsx [image]

I wish to create a file named: (Book Id)-(Chapter Id)-(Problem Id) for all 13 problems given in this Excel File. Each File should look like this:

[image: Ignore the file name, which is Docume]nt1.docx. It should be 52289-9.2-59PS.docx. But observe that the first line contains a **Bottom Border**, the file name on the left and the company name (which is constant) and today's date.

**I am having trouble in adding the border to the document and changing the font size and name.** This is the code that I have written so far.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from docx import Document
from time import strftime
from docx.shared import Pt
#Accessing data from excel file. 
ws=load_workbook(filename="Problems.xlsx")
sheet=ws.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
for i in range(2,15):
    fileName=""
    for j in range(1,4):
        if j!=3:
            fileName=fileName+str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=j).value)+"-"
        else:
            fileName=fileName+str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=j).value)
    #Now we have the file names, so let's make a file  
    document=Document()
    run=document.add_paragraph().add_run()
    font=run.font
    font.name="Times New Roman"
    font.size=12
    date=strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    document.add_paragraph(fileName+"                                                                                           AID: 1112|"+date)
    document.add_paragraph("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    #Saving the document with the fileName
    document.save(fileName+".docx")
```

The above code creates the files with the correct name, but there are two key issues:

1. The Font still remains Calibri instead of Times New Roman and the font size is 11 instead of 12.
2. I have added dashed lines for now, but I would really like to have a bottom border, for which you usually click on the button circled in red.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error, the following code works and fixes both the issues that I mentioned in my Question.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from docx import Document
from time import strftime
from docx.shared import Pt
#Accessing data from excel file. 
ws=load_workbook(filename="Problems.xlsx")
sheet=ws.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
for i in range(2,15):
    fileName=""
    for j in range(1,4):
        if j!=3:
            fileName=fileName+str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=j).value)+"-"
        else:
            fileName=fileName+str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=j).value)
    #Now we have the file names, so let's make a file  
    document=Document()
    style=document.styles['Normal']
    font=style.font
    font.name="Times New Roman"
    font.size=Pt(12)
    date=strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    font.underline=True
    document.add_paragraph(fileName+"                                                                       AID: 1112|"+date,style='Normal')
    #Saving the document with the fileName
    document.save(fileName+".docx")
```